# Android shared storage accessibility via PC

Tags: android, file, expansion

[Testing Your Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing)

says: ...
For example, if your package name is com.example.android, you need to create the directory Android/obb/com.example.android/ on the shared storage space. (Plug in your test device to your computer to mount the shared storage and manually create this directory.)

I found out(by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) that external storage is mounted as /mnt/sdcard in my device. So.. How can I access this storage via Windows to copy about 200Mb files?
BTW the device does not have a micro-SD plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adb push to push files to your device.  More documentation here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Good.  I have found that /mnt/sdcard/Android equals to Android in the root dir. /mnt/sdcard is mounted as root dir

Answer (score 0):

There’s also the [Android File Transfer app](https://android.com/filetransfer/) you can use to copy files from your Mac or PC.

And [as Andrew pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820718/android-shared-storage-accessibility-via-pc#comment17342771_12821065), the path reported by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` doesn’t necessarily match what you can see in the Android File Transfer app’s file system. In my case, the “Android” folder was also present in the root at `/Android` – and so I could ignore every path element before the “/Android/obb” part reported by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

So, to copy extension files into the appropriate directory on the device, I had to you copy them to `/Android/obb/com.example.android/` on the device.